# Authorize.net CIM user authentication failed due to invalid authentication values

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am currently experiencing this problem. the thing is that it is working perfectly in test mode, but when we try to use the live id and transaction key, we keep getting the error... I am thinking maybe the request is still trying to post to the test server and we need to force the request to the live one

here is our instantiation code

```
// authorize.net account credentials
$auth_test_mode = false;
if ($auth_test_mode) {
    define("AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID", "testid");
    define("AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY", "testkey");
} else {
   define("AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID", "ourid");
   define("AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY", "ourkey");
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to specify which URL you are using. The test server and live server use different URLs. If you don't change that, too, you'll get this error.

Comment: The Auth.net docs for the SDK are really poor.  I would use Stripe except Auth.net is cheaper.  Use this key: define("AUTHORIZENET_SANDBOX", false);

Answer (score 2):

If you are using authorizenet-php-api, then include this line too:

```
define("AUTHORIZENET_SANDBOX", false);
```

Also, FYI, you don't need defines for your API keys, you can use the functions like this:

```
authorizeNetGetDailyTransaction($account['loginID'],$account['transactionID'])
```

Which is the only way to do it if you have to login to multiple accounts from the same page.